# Referencing Resource Images in WPF Class Library without Citing Assembly Name

Tags: wpf, class, resources

I have this **WPF class library** with several (local) images marked as Resource. They are located in a subfolder named Resources. To reference them, I use the following markup:

```
Icon="/AssemblyName;component/Resources/Logo64x64.ico"
```

And everything works fine in this assembly.

My problem is that I want to use that xaml file in several assemblies with different names. That is, AssemblyName is subject to change from build to build. Is there a way to reference the resource images without dependency on AssemblyName? Or can I use something that dynamically refers to assembly name in the markup? Something like:

```
Icon="/%AssemblyName%;component/Resources/Logo64x64.ico"
```

Or do I have to update the AssemblyName every time? Is it a good idea to define properties in the backing C# code and then use binding? I have been avoiding this because it looked like a lot of code to me for referencing each image.

As far as I know, you cannot use pack URI's in class libraries, right? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you have different assemblies containing identically named image file resources, but sharing a common XAML file with references to these resources?

Comment: @Clemens, yes, even the image files are the same and shared among assemblies. Thank you for your comment, but I found out what to do, and the solution was in fact very simple -- more in the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this, but it turns out I can totally avoid using AssemblyName, since the resources are local and they can be referenced relatively. In my case, the xaml file is in another subfolder, so the resource should be referenced as:

```
Icon="../Resources/Logo64x64.ico"
```